# When connecting with flask-socketio get an error when loading html source files

Tags: python, flask-socketio, eventlet

I am using socket.io js (client) and connecting to flask-socketio (server).
The connection occurs, but I get an error in python when loading source files in my HTML. So it tried to first load the source files and then make the socket connection:

```
  window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    //Socket initial connection
    var socket = io('http://'+ document.domain + ':' + location.port);  
  })
```

However, I still get this error in python:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Apr/2018 12:47:16] "GET 
/static/video/video.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 200 1835327 0.771649
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\eventlet\hubs\selects.py", line 55, in wait
listeners.get(fileno, noop).cb(fileno)
File "C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\eventlet\greenthread.py", line 218, in main
result = function(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\eventlet\wsgi.py", line 781, in process_request
proto.__init__(conn_state, self)
File "C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\eventlet\wsgi.py", line 337, in __init__
self.finish()
File "C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\eventlet\wsgi.py", line 695, in finish
BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.finish(self)
File "C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 760, in finish
self.wfile.close()
File "C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socket.py", line 604, in write
return self._sock.send(b)
File "C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\eventlet\greenio\base.py", line 394, in send
return self._send_loop(self.fd.send, data, flags)
File "C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\eventlet\greenio\base.py", line 381, in _send_loop
return send_method(data, *args)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
Removing descriptor: 1656
```

From the trace it seems like eventlet is involved. At the top of my python program I have gevent:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all() #must be on top
```

I am not sure what is causing the issue. How do I address this error?

Comment: You should decide to use one of eventlet or gevent.

Comment: I am only only using gevent. It appears that somehow eventlet is involved.

Comment: @Dave uninstall eventlet from your virtual environment if you don't want to use it.